# Javascript Create New "Thread"

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

This is a "thread" according to javascript, but the code doesn't seem to fit the conventional threaded model.

Is it possible to make this code clearer, with regards to the concept of a thread?

```
function test() {
    alert("Test");
}

// this creates a new "thread," but doesn't make much sense to the untrained eye
setTimeout(test, 0);
```

Is there some other way to branch off?

Comment: But the execution of the test function will be on the main thread, so if your test has some heavy code, your server or app will hang. The timekeeping of the timeout only happens asynchronously. I think workes would be most closely in terms of thread.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are basically just taking the call to `test` out of the normal flow and the engine will execute the function whenever it fits, as soon as possible. That means, you are executing `test` *asynchronously*.

To make the code clearer, you could create a function with a meaningful name which does the same:

```
function executeAsync(func) {
    setTimeout(func, 0);
}

executeAsync(function() {
    alert("Test");
});
```

If you want to have real threads, have a look at [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: I just need to run asynchronously, threads aren't necessary.  Thanks!

Comment: Web workers arn't an option for most web applications (see link)  Basically, IE 10 is the first version to support it. http://caniuse.com/webworkers

Comment: A lot has changed since @komma8.komma1's comment.  Now you can use web workers in almost all browsers!