# Methods to reduce apparent lag to client from large javascript operations

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, google-chrome-extension

As part of my Chrome Extension, I am performing a few regex replaces on a lot of (upwards of 3000) elements on the document end event. In the worst cases, in Chrome 34.0.1847.116 m on a pretty decent PC, the operation can take >180 seconds to complete, and during this time, the webpage is frozen.

Is there, and if so, what is the best way to either mitigate the operation over a longer time span, or give the operation a *"lower priority"* so that it doesn't take 100% while running.

The script is pretty much nested jQuery each functions all running a regex replace using a large expression. These expressiond search for 3000-4000 words and then replaces it with some html. An example one is (searching for specific reddit names)

```
/(\s|/u/|^)(name1|name2|name3|...|name500)([^\w]|$)/
```

If it helps, you can see the full source [here](https://github.com/GusGold/DogeRedditHelper-Chrome/blob/master/js/content_script/setup.js#L150).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you're really getting performance issues, start with profiling the performance using the developer tools. Then you will probably see that jQuery has too much overhead (DOM is expensive, and an abstraction of DOM, like jQuery is even more expensive). If you replace your jQuery code with optimized vanilla JS, then the performance will probably increase.

Comment: @RobW I took your advice and replaced jQuery with vanilla. In my case, it's actually ~10% slower according to Chrome's profiller.

Comment: [Literally translating jQuery to Vanilla JS](https://github.com/GusGold/DogeRedditHelper-Chrome/commit/1e9694873a6d08349f2d8482f8708565d9e24a59) doesn't bring any performance benefits. You've still kept the same abstraction (not in the form of jQuery, but some (inferior) custom method). Optimized vannila JS is code that minimizes the use of DOM and avoids repaints and re-parses. Your new code does LOTS of HTML re-parsing because of `.innerHTML += ...` Use [`.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) instead.

Comment: @RobW Most of my code is replacing elements, rather than append/prepending. [This](https://github.com/GusGold/DogeRedditHelper-Chrome/blob/master/js/content_script/setup.js#L162) is where 99% of my extension's execution time is spent, with 0.999% used [here](https://github.com/GusGold/DogeRedditHelper-Chrome/blob/master/js/content_script/highlighter.js#L2). In my /novice/ mind, I can't see how `.insetAdjacentHTML` would benefit me?

Comment: `content` is apparently text, but you're [using `.innerHTML` to assing the new value](https://github.com/GusGold/DogeRedditHelper-Chrome/blob/210fb1bec4e93ed11b57fbb24a54cd9aafd013a7/js/content_script/setup.js#L196). If parsing the RegExp is expensive, then store the regexp in data.xxx.regex instead of a string representing the regexp. You might want to explore some perf tests on http://jsperf.com. E.g. in http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-innertext/4, you can clearly see that innerHTML is by far inferior over nodeValue.

Comment: (not related to performance, but https://github.com/GusGold/DogeRedditHelper-Chrome/blob/210fb1bec4e9/js/content_script/setup.js#L232-L246 is going to break all existing code in the web page.)

Comment: @RobW Ahh, thanks on the `nodeValue`, and as for breaking the page, it /seems/ to still function all a-okay, but would that be the time for `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "new html");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the long operations in a new thread using the `setTimeout` function and a callback on completion.

See [Javascript Create New "Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373987/javascript-create-new-thread)

Comment: I tried wrapping it in a setTimeout callback, but it still froze the webpage. Am I right in assuming even though it is asynchronously called, it still uses as much cpu time as possible to be completed, causing the page to freeze?

Comment: @GusGold ok, so try using webworkers, or splitting your function into smaller tasks and running each one using setTimeout. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998330/how-to-do-threading-in-javascript

Comment: If I were to try out the setTimeouts every so often, what would be a good on/off time. Like ~ 1s of work, then 1s timeout, or something a lot quicker like 200ms on/off. Or would something like 800ms on, 200ms off work best? I would prefer the operation to have as little effect on the client, whilst still being completed in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @GusGold It's hard to answer, I suggest you start with some trial and error until you find the best balance for your case.

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded, using `setTimeout` queues the new task in the event loop, it does not "move" calculations to a "new thread" or anything like that.