# Nonconcurrent async recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, google-chrome-extension

My end goal is to mitigate as much lag (window freezing/stuttering) as possible, giving the client a responsive window from page load.

My program is a Chrome extension, and part of it needs to search through a reddit submission, including all comments for certain words and then do some stuff with them. After [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23053821/2803348), I converted [my code](https://github.com/GusGold/DogeRedditHelper-Chrome) to use setInterval for the recursive search. Unforutnately, this runs concurrently, so even though each branch in the comment tree is delayed from its parent, the overall search overlaps each other, negating any benefit in the delay.

I have a solution, but I don't know how to implement it.

The solution would be to have a callback when a branch runs out that goes to the nearest parent fork. This in effect would traverse the comment tree linearly and would allow the setInterval (or probably setTimeout would be more appropriate) to have a noticeable affect.

---

The code that would need to be changed is:

```
function highlightComments(){
    var elems = $(".content .usertext-body > .md");
    var index = 0;
    var total = elems.length;
    console.log("comments started");
    var intId = setInterval(function(){
        highlightField(elems.get(index));
        index++;
        if(index == total){
            clearInterval(intId);
            addOnClick();
            console.log("comments finished");
        }
    }, 25);
}
```

and highlightField is:

```
function highlightField(node) {
    var found = $(node).attr("data-ggdc-found") === "1";
    var contents = $.makeArray($(node).contents());
    var index = 0;
    var total = contents.length;
    if (total == 0){
        return;
    }

    var intId = setInterval(function() {
        if (contents[index].nodeType === 3) { // Text
            if (!found){
                //Mods
                var content = contents[index].nodeValue.replace(new RegExp(data.mods.regex, "gi"), data.mods.replacement);

                //Creators
                content = content.replace(new RegExp(data.creators.regex, "gi"), data.creators.replacement);

                //Blacklist
                for (var key in data.blacklist.regex){
                    if(data.blacklist.regex.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                        content = content.replace(new RegExp(data.blacklist.regex[key], "gi"), data.blacklist.replacement[key]);
                    }
                }
                if (content !== contents[index].nodeValue) {
                    $(contents[index]).replaceWith(content);
                }
            }
        } else if (contents[index].nodeType === 1) { // Element
            highlightField(contents[index]);
        }
        index++;
        if(index == total){
            clearInterval(intId);
        }
    }, 25);
}
```

Comment: Step 1: Do not use jQuery... Short code does not equate fast code.

Comment: @RobW Even with removing jQuery, I would still like to have it run as explained. Do you have a anything to contribute to the actual question?

Comment: That was a serious comment. Your code is highly inefficient due to jQuery. As said on your other question, DOM manipulation is often the bottleneck in a web application. Using jQuery, which provides a generic abstraction for it, could ease development, but at the cost of performance. You could use a [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) for traversal, and `oldNode.parentNode.replaceChild(newNode, oldNode)` to replace `replaceWith`, `node.childNodes` instead of `$.makeArray($(node)).contents()` and `node.dataset.gddcFound` instead of `$(node).attr(...)`.