# Receiving warning about Synchronous XMLHttpRequest in asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

My browser (or the JQuery framework, to be more specific) prints the following warning to the browser's console:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

I understand the warning, but not why it appears. To my understanding the call of asyncFunct() **is** asynchronous and therefore shouldn't print the warning message.

I'm using this JavaScript code:

```js
var i18nObject;

$(document).ready(function () {
    // execute asyncFunct() asynchronously
    setTimeout(asyncFunct, 3000);
});

function asyncFunct() {
    alert(i18n("rejoin.title"));
}

function i18n(key) {
    if (typeof i18nObject == 'undefined') {
        // i18n not loaded yet, need to load it first
        $.ajax({
            url: 'UrlTo/i18n.json',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                i18nObject = response;
            }
        });
    }
    if (i18nObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // key found
        return i18nObject[key];
    } else {
        // key not found
        return key;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To face some concerns (from the comments) about `async: false`: This was deliberately chosen, as I need the function to return a value. I understand that using synchronous calls is a bad idea if they lock the UI. But why does this apply to my problem here? I want the call to asyncFunct() to be asynchronous.

Why am I receiving this warning, and is it possible to disable it? (to prevent unnecessary text in the console)

Comment: It is clearly telling you not to use `async: false,` which is a terrible practice in the first place. Handle your response in the success callback. See [how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: That warning suggests that if you want to use `async: false`, you should do it off the main thread. Take a look at using [Web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: I've fixed this problem now by moving the i18n() call inside the done-function of another AJAX call. This works great for my specific problem (as I need to make the call anyways), but I'm still interested why this message was shown in the first place.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the link. In my case the i18n() function should only do the AJAX call if the i18nObject was not loaded previously. Is there a way to return it without making unnecessary AJAX calls (or returning a "call me again later, I'm still fetching value")?

Comment: google the error for a full explanation

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, If I've been unclear. I understand the error and the solution to the problem the error refers to. But I do NOT understand why the error applies to me. (This was the original question). By making the i18n() do a asynchronous call, it is no longer able to return a value. Therefore I can't use this solution. (Please correct me, if I'm wrong somewhere! - I don't have a lot of experience with JS and greatly appreciate any help)

Comment: you made it `synchronous` is why by setting `async: false` You can pass a callback into your function and make it work fine asynchronously ... or return a promise from your function

Comment: @charlietfl Using a callback function seems like a good solution. Thanks.
However, I think I think I still didn't fully understand why the call is synchronous. I de-synchronized asyncFunct() from the main thread by using setTimeout(). Shouldn't this mean that all functions called by asyncFunct() (i.e. i18n()) are also de-synchronized?

Comment: You are mixing up 2 different concepts. The warning is about using `XMLHttpRequest` ($.ajax) in synchronous mode. It has nothing to do with using setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

Actually, since you are putting the sync call inside of a timeout, it appears that the call *does* happen asynchronously, as you correctly pointed out (see [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zajoyovuxe/1/edit?js,output) for an example):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk',
    success: function(res) {
      console.log(res);
    },
    async: false
  });
}, 1000);

console.log('something synchronous');
```

If you open up the console, you'll notice that (as expected), `something synchronous` is logged first, and then a little over a second later, the result from our API is logged.

So I feel like there are two parts to this question that need to be addressed.

The first part is, why are you forcing a sync call to happen async, using a deprecated API, when you could just avoid the timeout altogether and simply make your XMLHttpRequest naturally asynchronous?

The second part is about suppressing the warning. It appears that the warning happens mistakenly, but the warning isn't looking at the fact that you made the sync request inside of a timeout. It's simply looking at the fact that you are using a deprecated API. In other words, the warning only cares about the usage of the deprecated API itself, and not the specific implementation.

However, if you really want to suppress these warnings, it'll be an all or nothing deal (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1215400/2714730) for an example):

```
// define this as an empty function in your own code
console.log = function() {};
```

## Original answer

> To my understanding the call of asyncFunct() is asynchronous and therefore shouldn't print the warning message.

False.

Your call is *not* asynchronous. It is synchronous, because you have `async: false`.

This warning is because synchronous requests block the main thread (the same thread that handles UI, for example). This can ruin the user's experience using the site/app. Thus, the warning shows up in the console.

Comment: Thanks, this explains the warning, but could you explain WHY the call is synchronous? I've read http://stackoverflow.com/a/7374037/3298787 where it (to my understanding) says "calling a function with setTimeout() makes it asynchrounous"

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer. The reason I used a synchronous call is: I'll need to load translated messages from a json object  (server-side, based on the clients `accept-language`, generated). I want to avoid making unnecessary calls to the object (--> cache it in "i18nObject"). To simplify this process I designated a single function for it: "i18n()" 

I will only need this function when I'm already de-synchronized from the main thread (--> asyncFunct()) and I'd like to avoid over-complication i18n() with a callback function

Comment: @Nijin22, no prob. Okay that makes sense. I'm not sure off the top of my head of a better way to do it than what you're doing, but I would probably spend a bit of time investigating whether or not you can find a less "hacky"-feeling way of doing it. But the concept you're talking about makes sense (that is, caching the database object on the client).

Comment: Thank you. I tried a lot of alternatives (generated & localized javascript, messages pre-loaded in the HTML, etc.) but haven't found one which works better than this with my current framework. I also dislike the current solution, but at least it is one which does work.